# Prove there is a Borel measure u such that $u[x,y) = a(y) - a(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If anyone has a solution to the following exercise, I would be grateful.  Thanks.

> Let $\alpha$ be continuous and increasing on $[a,b]$.  Prove that there exists a unique Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R$ such that $ \mu[x,y) = \alpha(y) - \alpha(x) $  for all $x < y$.

Answer (score 1):

- If $S$ is a finite disjoint union of sets of the form $[a_i,b_i)$, where $a\leqslant a_i<b_i<b$, we can define $\mu(S)$ by $\sum_i (\alpha(b_i)-\alpha(a_i))$.
- Then we can extend to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by these sets thanks to [Carathérodory's extension's theorem](http://planetmath.org/caratheodorysextensiontheorem).